# Can we configure two different servers in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, server, configuration

I already have a tomcat server in ecilpse but I wish to work with wildfly as well so I added a new wildfly server to the server but when I tried to start the server it gives a error "java bind except: address already in use" but the first server was not started.
If my guess is right when installing tomcat it was bind to a port so when I added a new server it tries to use the same which gives this error.

I'm I right is there was to have both severs configure.
Eg. If I wish to work with wildfly I would like to stop the tomcat and start wildfly which would also listen at 8080.
Basically like switching servers.
I'm doing this because I find tomcat creating server-config.wsdd file when we use webservice wizard to create a webservice while some servers fail to create the wsdd file.

Comment: "java bind except: address already in use" this mean port is already in use. The command to check the same in linux is $netstat -anp | grep 8080

Comment: change the port by specifying sever.port option env variables in eclipse.